# How can I see the strackrace that includes the frames generated by my methods?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio, callstack

In Android Studio,I run the app in Debug mode which loads it into the emulator. Then I go through the app clicking through the UI so my user defined methods are called as to generate a stack trace. I press pause,look into the Debugger->threads and frames window but it only shows the general platform specific frames and nothing of  mine. 
When I set a break point my frames do appear, but why doesn't it work when I just press pause? why wouldn't all frames be visible till that point?

So how can I see the strackrace that also includes the frames generated by my methods,without having placed a breakpoint, if not why isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to count how much time passed since you'd interacted with your UI and till you pressed debugger's "Pause" button. This time is quite enough to leave your own methods and return back to framework code, that has called your listeners / callbacks.

To see stack traces without any debugger involving just use:

```
new Throwable("tada!!!").printStackTrace();
```

Then just check logcat output. Alternatively you can store `Throwable` and print its stack trace later. To convert it to string - use `Log.getStackTraceString()`.

Comment: so there in way to get 'built-in' behaviour by the debugger,you have to intervene in the process